# Django: Check in template if queryset is empty

Tags: django, templates, view, django-queryset

I have found the solution for this but only by checking in views so far. I need to check in templates.

My view:

```
brands = Brand.objects.all()
for brand in brands:
    brand.products = Product.objects.filter(brand=brand.id)
```

And so in my template I want to show all my brands but not those which do not have any product.

```
{% for brand in brands %}
    {% if brand.product is not None %}
        <!-- Displays brand -->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Something like that, but the code `is not None` doesn't work for empty querysets and it is still displaying brands with no objects in them. What can I do?

EDIT: Sharing model as requested.

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    brand = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Can you share your models please?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem for sure. Done! If you can tell me any solution without making a one-to-one relationship I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Hold on, you did not use a `ForeignKey` here? Please change the `IntegerField` to a `ForeignKey`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/ it will add extra database constraints, and make the Django ORM more expressive, it will also create a better modeling layer.

Comment: That's a great solution and I appreciate your help, but the problem is that I am migrating a desktop Windows application, and I must keep the DB tables as they currently are.

Comment: except for renaming `brand` to `brand_id`, not much will change at the "database" layer, but it will make the model more consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template should be like:

```
{% for brand in brands %}
    {% if brand.product %}
        <!-- Displays brand -->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Note that the second example will not work, since Django templates do *not* allow function calls (well not explicit ones at least).

Answer (score 2):

It is usually *not* a good idea to use `IntegerField`s, etc. to represent relations. Django uses [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) to implement such relations. There are multiple advantages for this: (1) it will add extra constraints to the database, such that the key can only refer to a real `Brand`; and (2) you will have extra ways to retrieve the related `Product`s.

The `Product` model thus should have a `ForeignKey` to the `Brand` model, like:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, null=True, db_column='brand')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, null=False)
```

Here we leave the database structure itself intact, but it will add a `ForeignKey` on it, as well as an *index*, making retrieving all products for a given `Brand` much faster.

It is usually a bad idea to write (business)logic in templates. In fact one of the reasons why the Django template language does not allow to make calls with parameters, etc. is to avoid that people write business logic in the template. So I strongly advice you to shift the logic to the view.

You can retrieve the `Brand`s that at least have *one* related `Product` in the *view* with a one-liner:

```
Brand.objects.filter(product__isnull=False).distinct()
```

So it is *not* necessary to check each brand individually. Here we also check the existance of a `Product` in a *single* query for all `Brand`s, not an extra query per `Brand` to check if there are related `Product`s.

This will result in a query that looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT brand.*
FROM brand
INNER JOIN product ON brand.id = product.brand_id
WHERE product.id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display something different when a collection is empty, check this out:

```
{% for i in list %}
    // Do this in non - empty condition
{% empty %}
    // Do this in empty condition
{% endfor %}
```

credit: [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/for-empty-loop-django-template-tags/)

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution using {% empty %} inside my for worked for me.

```
{% for detallesblog in object_list %}
  <label for="detalles" class="negritatxt">Detalles</label>

    <p>
      {{ detallesblog.detalles }}
    </p>

    <label for="logo" class="negritatxt">Logo</label>

    <p>
      <img src="{% static 'uploads/' %}{{ detallesblog.logo }} " class="img-fluid" alt="{{ detallesblog.logo }}">          
    </p>

    <label for="updated_at" class="negritatxt">Fecha de Actualización</label>
    <p>
      {{ detallesblog.updated_at }}
    </p>
    <a href="detallesblog/editar/{{ detallesblog.id }}" title="Editar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Editar Datos</a>
{% empty %}

    "You have not yet edited the details of your Blog", press the "Edit Data" button to do so.
    <
    <a href="detallesblog/editar/{{ detallesblog.id }}" title="Editar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Editar Datos</a>

{% endfor %}
```

You can adapt it to your needs